# Levitation using Electromagnets - Forces

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, forces, magnetic-fields, free-body-diagram

Here is a hypothetical (but potential real) situation:

I am holding electromagnet that weights 1kg. This electromagnet is being used to hold up a 10kg weight.

Would I feel like I am holding 11kg, or 1kg?

Basically  what I am asking is - When an electromagnet is suspending a weight, is the force cancelled out through the electromagnet or transferred to whatever is holding up the electromagnet.

Comment: it feels you are holding $11\ \mathrm{kg}$. Imagine you are holding instead, a square piece of wood. If you put something (say, a small box) on it, it will weight more overall. Whatever you put on the piece of wood is not really *touching* it; the electromagnetic force between the atoms is really holding the box where it is. The only difference in the case of the magnet is that you can see the space in between. In the case of the piece of wood, the space in-between is very small, and you cannot see it, but its there, just as with the magnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to feel that force if you are holding up the electromagnet.  This is because there is an equal and opposite force on the electromagnet you are holding.  If you draw a free body diagram, you will see that the magnet you are holding has both the force of gravity acting on it and the magnetic force from the other magnet as well as the force of your hand holding it up.  The force of your hand holding it up will have to balance both gravity and this magnetic force.  The magnetic force will be equal to the force required to balance the other magnet against gravity.  So in essence, you will feel the weight of both objects combined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a expert so correct me if needed. Magnets work like any other matter in gravity until they are put next to each other. Even if the magnets don't touch they still have their atomic weight. Magnets doesn't defy gravity, but they do have their own quantum physics. On a sale the weight from the top and bottom magnet is still the same.

Comment: What the other guy said too.